# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value array is a get-only property swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsmutablearray

I understand the problem, but I don't know how to solve it, I found other thread, but they are very specific problem.
I have my for var:

```
    static var DeliveryStatusArray =
    [
        "claimable": [],
        "onTime": [],
        "future": [],
        "claimDone": [],
        "tooOld": [],
    ]
```

My function is :

```
    static func moreCard(status:String, newJson: JSON)
{
    var json = JSON(DeliveryStatusArray[status] as Any)
    var tmpArray = json[0]["cards"].arrayValue

    newJson["cards"].array?.insert(tmpArray, at: 0)
    DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray[status]?.removeAll()
    DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray[status] = tmpArray
}
```

In this function I want to insert at the begining of newJson["cards"] tmpArray. In second time I need to pass newJson at DeliveryStatusArray["status"]. I got my error on the line

> newJson["cards"].array?.insert(tmpArray, at: 0)

In my view, the prototype of my function is:`DashboardManager.moreCard(status: section, newJson: json["data"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift only allows constants as the method parameter. In your case to fix the problem, you can use the inout parameter in the method as below.

```
  static func moreCard(status:String, newJson: inout JSON)
  {
     var json = JSON(DeliveryStatusArray[status] as Any)
     var tmpArray = json[0]["cards"].arrayValue

     newJson["cards"].array?.insert(tmpArray, at: 0)
     DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray[status]?.removeAll()
     DashboardManager.DeliveryStatusArray[status] = tmpArray
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to change my prototype ?
When I change it to **DashboardManager.moreCard(status: section, newJson: json["data"])** 
I still have the same error, and if I don't change the prototype,  I have the error **Passing value of type 'Json' to an inout parameter requires explicit &**

Comment: No just pass pre-created prototype object in the inout parameter and you will be able to mutate that object in your method. Parameter to be passed in the method will be DashboardManager.moreCard(status: section, newJson: &json["data"]) or  `var jsondata = json["data"]  then DashboardManager.moreCard(status: section, newJson: &jsondata)`